# How to convert curl_exec response to associative array?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$real_result=curl_exec($ch);
echo $real_result;
```

I see the following result: `{"result":"LOGIN","old_value":"1"}`
I need to convewrt $real_result to simple associative array, because I need to compare that with another array. I have tried it:

```
$data=json_decode($real_result);
array_intersect(json_decode($real_result), $expected_result);
```

But it doesn't work and I have got the message that the first argument is not an array. So, please, tell me how I can do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set the second parameter with `true` to get array.

```
$data=json_decode($real_result, true);
```